# Is $\sin\left(\frac xy\right)$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: continuity

I am unable to find by definition the continuity of the following function $$ f(x,y)=\sin\left(\frac xy\right)$$ at $(0,0)$
I have substituted $$x=my$$ and found the limit to be non-existent and hence the function as discontinuous at $$(0,0)$$. Am I correct?

Comment: What do you know about the continuity of $x/y$ ?

Comment: I substituted $$x=my$$ and found the limit to be non-existent. So I concluded that it is not continuous. However, I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @rah22ul That last commentary you should put **in the body of your question**, so that everybody knows what you have done and where you're having doubts. By the way, what you did is correct: that proves the limit doesn't exist as you get the constant function $\;\sin m\;$ .

Answer (score 3):

I think you can look at those two parametric curves

1. $(t, t)$ where $t\to 0$
2. $(t, t^2)$ where $t\to 0$

to figure out the limit doesn't exist (could have commented but don't have enough reputation to do so)

Comment: Your answer is correct, and now you have a little more reputation. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The function is not defined at $\langle0,0\rangle$ hence is not continuous at $\langle0,0\rangle$.

Another question is: can we expand the function by giving it a value at $\langle0,0\rangle$ in such a way that this expanded function is continuous at $\langle0,0\rangle$?

Again the answer is: "no".

The sequences $(\langle\frac1{n},\frac1{n}\rangle)_n$ and $(\langle\frac2{n},\frac1{n}\rangle)_n$ both converge to $\langle0,0\rangle$ but substituting them in $f(x,y)$ gives us two convergent sequences having distinct limits ($\sin1\neq\sin2$).

That contradicts continuity at $\langle0,0\rangle$ of any expansion of the function at $\langle0,0\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

put $y=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ and again put  $y=\frac{1}{n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Clearly $y\longrightarrow‎ 0$ when $n\longrightarrow‎ \infty$ but $sin(\frac{x}{y})\nrightarrow‎ 0$.